# How to store each dataframes row value in a string and execute URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
        symbol
0   https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ACC&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
1   https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ADANIENT&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
2   https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ADANIPORTS&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
3   https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ADANIPOWER&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020
4   https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=AMARAJABAT&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020

.....
```

I want to read the dataframe row by row into a string and execute following sample code

For example:

```
# 1st time
# url=https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ACC&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020

headers = { "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78"}

r=requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
df1=pd.DataFrame().from_records(r["data"])
df2=df1[['CH_SYMBOL','mTIMESTAMP','CH_OPENING_PRICE','CH_CLOSING_PRICE','CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE','CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE']]

# 2nd row

# https://nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ADANIENT&series=["EQ"]&from=07-01-2020&to=11-01-2020

headers = { "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate","Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.9",
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36 OPR/65.0.3467.78"}

r=requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
df1=pd.DataFrame().from_records(r["data"])
df2=df1[['CH_SYMBOL','mTIMESTAMP','CH_OPENING_PRICE','CH_CLOSING_PRICE','CH_TRADE_HIGH_PRICE','CH_TRADE_LOW_PRICE']]
```

My questions are:

1. How to iterate over the dataframe and store dataframe row values in text/a string without an index so I can execute the above code?
2. Is there any better way to do this than reading the dataframe row by row?
3. It is not important, but when I display dataframe 'symbol' column values are getting displayed right justified. I tried `df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How to iterate dataframe and store Dataframe row value in text/string without index so I can execute above code

You could extract the values of a column and store them in a `np.array` like this `a = df['symbol'].values`.  After that you could transform that code-block into a function and apply  [numpy.vectorize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

> 2. Is there any betterway to do this rather than reading dataframe row by row

One way that I think is more elegant is to again transform your code-block into a function that takes as a parameter a string and apply that function on the column `symbol` with [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
#the function from that code-block
def my_func(s):
...

df['symbol'].apply(my_func)
```

Hope this helps